# YARN job failed when running from Windows

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-boot, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run Spring Boot YARN [sample](https://spring.io/guides/gs/yarn-basic/) on Windows.

On my VM does run single node Hadoop 2.7.1.

When I'm trying to run the app from Windows using `java -jar ...`, Spring Yarn deploys all jars successfully - I can browse and observe them in Hadoop FS.
While running program in cluster (host:8088/cluster) I can see that app is submitted, then runs container and after that app fails with next exception in logs:

```
Application application_1496328851344_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1496328851344_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://host:8088/cluster/app/application_1496328851344_0001 Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1496328851344_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: /bin/bash: line 0: fg: (null): no job control
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: /bin/bash: line 0: fg: (null): no job control
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

But when I'm starting app on VM - everything works.

Here are my Hadoop config files:

`core-site.xml:`

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://192.168.0.106:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

`hdfs-site.xml:`

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/data/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/data/datanode</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

`mapred-site.xml:`

```
<configuration>
    <property>
       <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
       <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

`yarn-site.xml:`

```
<configuration>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
       <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
        <value>5</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**UPD** setting `mapreduce.app-submission.cross-platform` property to `true` doesn't help.

Comment: same issue, do you got a solution  ?

Comment: @Keith, unfortunately, no:(

Comment: Mine is resolved  :) . I suspect you are not using the right hadoop-yarn-client jar , it has the %PWD% issue in the version before 2.2 and fixed in later version. So , check your yarn version.

Comment: @Keithm I'm using the same hadoop-yarn-client as Spring do- 2.7.1

Comment: I saw that bugs and checked my hadoop sources to have that fixes.